# NetCDF - What is is 'phony_dim_0', 'phony_dim_1', 'phony_dim_2'?

Tags: netcdf, netcdf4

I am very new to using NetCDF files and I am at the exploratory stage trying to understand what this file could do. I am using 'netCDF4' python library. I am trying to find what does 'phony_dim_0', 'phony_dim_1', 'phony_dim_2' mean and contains? I am thinking it could be 'lat','lon', and/or 'time'?

Loading nc file

```
ds = nc.Dataset('my_file.nc')
type(ds)
>>> netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset
```

Printing Keys

```
print(ds.dimensions.keys())
>>> dict_keys(['phony_dim_0', 'phony_dim_1', 'phony_dim_2'])
```

Extract what is in this key?

```
ds.dimensions['phony_dim_0']
>>> <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'phony_dim_0', size = 1179
```

Error:

```
for c in ds.dimensions['phony_dim_0']:
    print(c) # Want to see what is in this? # Errors: TypeError: 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Try plotting the data. That should tell you what is what

Comment: I thought of that however, when I do this `ds.dimensions['phony_dim_0'][:]`. I get error `TypeError: 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension' object is not subscriptable`. I don't how to get the information inside of this dimension group.

Comment: That happens when the underlying hdf5 has no dimension scale attached. Then netcdf - c invents anonymous dimensions (aka phony_dim). Your data provider should know more about this.